# How to query firebase database for contains clause

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query firebase database with name contains the search text, In Android.
My database structure is shown in image.

[image]

I want to query first name and last name and get limited records in result.

Comment: Firebase queries can only order/filter by a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can get around this problem is to concatenate first name and last name into a new couple. Something like this: First_Last_Name: "Rahul_Rajesh". Just be noticed that this way causes redundancy and you should avoid it unless you REALLY need it.